# Add one Column from Dataframe to another Dataframe, but at the right position

Tags: pandas, dataframe, join, merge, compare

Hy all! i have some Dataframes that look look like this

```
           FSvalue 
Season           
1966-1967    288.0
1967-1968    129.0
1968-1969    384.0
1969-1970    507.0
1970-1971    236.0

           FSvalue
Season            
1965-1966  384.000
1966-1967  496.999
1967-1968  197.000
1968-1969  382.000
1969-1970  458.000
```

Now i want to combine the Frames, Season should stay in first place and FSvalue should be added
from the other frames to one big frame. The problem is, that they dont start with the same season.

I want the values from the second frame to stand at the correct position in the new combined frame.
So the Final Frame should have 1 column with Season and 4 columns with the values(i have 4 frames in total), but at the right Row depending on the season

my code looks like this, but x4 for all files:

df_a = pd.read_csv('xxxFreshSnowperSeason.csv', delimiter=",", dtype = {'Season': str, 'FSvalue': float})
df_a.set_index('Season',  inplace=True)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) with aggregate `sum`:

```
df = pd.concat([df_a, df_b, df_c, df_d], axis=1).groupby(level=0).sum()
```